# Don't pretend I can do the impossible

Tags: discussion, user-interface

There are many cases where I'm given the option to do something, only to find out much later that it's impossible.

For example:

- I voted to reopen a question. The "reopen (4)" still appears. If I click it, I'm alerted, "Nominate this question for reopening?" If I then click okay, I'm told that I already voted.
- If I don't have enough reputation to upvote (questions or comments) or downvote, the icons still appear.
- This was really annoying: I wanted to delete my own question. I clicked "delete" and a popup showed, asking if I was absolutely sure. In this case I was, so I clicked "Delete Question" only to receive a vague error message suggesting that I ask for a moderator's help.

Is there a reason for this confusing behavior? If I can't do something, why wait to the last possible moment to tell me?